# Mysql Or condition needs to be check only if first condition fail

Tags: mysql, database

**scenario**:

I need to show static user message if user not exist
I tried below Query, Or condition needs to be check only if first condition fail but i get both user message.

```
SELECT message_id, to_user, status FROM message_status USE INDEX (from_user,to_user) 
WHERE (from_user = '0e005822-8001-4a4d-be47-d078f3a5e4f6'
and (to_user = '90e0e182-a4fb-11ec-b909-0242ac120002'
 OR to_user = 'static123456789'));
```

[image]

Comment: Can't see from user in your sample , does the static to_user exist for every from_user even if there are other to_users for that from_user? Sample data as text would help.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Please check now.

Comment: Text would have been better. As far as I can tell to_user relates to message_id and if a message_id has a to_user in addition to static irrespective of the order in which the occur static should be ignored.

Comment: add `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query. This will make sure you will only get the first records of the result. Warning: you should also add an `ORDER BY` to make sure that the first record is the record that you are interested in .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT message_id, to_user, status FROM message_status USE INDEX (from_user,to_user)
WHERE from_user = '0e005822-8001-4a4d-be47-d078f3a5e4f6'
AND (CASE WHEN (to_user = '90e0e182-a4fb-11ec-b909-0242ac120002')
THEN TRUE
ELSE (to_user = 'static123456789') END)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i got same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a not exists test to test if there are tousers other than static for a message and union

```
DROP table if exists t;

create table t(fromuser varchar(3), message_id int,touser varchar(10));

insert into t values
('aaa','1','bbb'),
('aaa','1','static'),
('aaa','2','bbb');

select fromuser,message_id,touser 
from t where not exists (select 1 from t t1 where t1.message_id = t.message_id and t1.touser <> 'static' limit 1)
union all
select fromuser,message_id,touser from t where touser <> 'static';



+----------+------------+--------+
| fromuser | message_id | touser |
+----------+------------+--------+
| aaa      |          1 | bbb    |
| aaa      |          2 | bbb    |
+----------+------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```